# Проверка if несколько раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть необходимость при изменении значения переменной, менять текст в заголовке.

```
   if(currentSlide==1) {
    $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена')
  }
  else if(currentSlide==2) {
    $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена2')
  }
  else {
    $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена3')
  }
```

Реализовал так, замена происходит 1 раз, после чего уже вне зависимости от значения currentSlide, пока не обновлю страницу значение в заголовке не меняется. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А как происходит изменения значения currentSlide?

Comment: при смене слайда, по клику на стрелку. Но даже если сделать так                                      
 $( ".next" ).click(function() {
  var counter = 1;
   if (counter == 1) {
    counter++;
    $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена')
  }
  else if (counter == 2) {
    $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена2')
  }
  else {
      $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена3')
  }
});


});

Comment: Тоесть если отследить каждый клик по стрелке, добавить переменную счетчик и добавлять +1 при каждом клике на стрелку выполняется только 1 раз тоесть пишет Замена, дальше не идет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте ваш код в функцию и вызывайте ее при клике, инкремент делайте также в функции, а объявление вне функции. Самый простой и топорный вариант.

```
var currentSlide = 0;
$('.next').on('click', onClickSlider )

function onClickSlider() {
    currentSlide++;
    if ( currentSlide==1 ) {
        $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена')
    }
    else if ( currentSlide==2 ) {
        $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена2')
    }
    else {
        $('.works-slider-h').text('Замена3')
    }
}
```